How can I simplify this piece of javscript code
I'm sure this JS piece of JavaScript code can be simplified... I'm trying to reduce the amount of code lines and believe this can be condensed and merged into a shorter version? It's basically a decision tree with yes | no choices and results appear according to user yes | no selection.


document.getElementById('yesButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('noPanel').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('yesPanel').classList.remove('hidden');
  document.getElementById('keepPanel').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('sellPanel').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('gainNoPanel').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('gainYesPanel').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('cgtNoPanel').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('cgtYesPanel').classList.add('hidden');
});

document.getElementById('noButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('yesPanel').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('noPanel').classList.remove('hidden');
  document.getElementById('keepPanel').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('sellPanel').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('gainNoPanel').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('gainYesPanel').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('cgtNoPanel').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('cgtYesPanel').classList.add('hidden');
});

document.getElementById('keepButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('keepPanel').classList.remove('hidden');
  document.getElementById('sellPanel').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('gainNoPanel').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('gainYesPanel').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('cgtNoPanel').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('cgtYesPanel').classList.add('hidden');
});

document.getElementById('sellButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('sellPanel').classList.remove('hidden');
  document.getElementById('keepPanel').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('gainNoPanel').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('gainYesPanel').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('cgtNoPanel').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('cgtYesPanel').classList.add('hidden');
});

document.getElementById('gainNoButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('gainNoPanel').classList.remove('hidden');
  document.getElementById('gainYesPanel').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('cgtNoPanel').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('cgtYesPanel').classList.add('hidden');
});

document.getElementById('gainYesButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('gainYesPanel').classList.remove('hidden');
  document.getElementById('gainNoPanel').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('cgtNoPanel').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('cgtYesPanel').classList.add('hidden');
});

document.getElementById('cgtNoButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('cgtNoPanel').classList.remove('hidden');
  document.getElementById('cgtYesPanel').classList.add('hidden');
});

document.getElementById('cgtYesButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('cgtYesPanel').classList.remove('hidden');
  document.getElementById('cgtNoPanel').classList.add('hidden');
});
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
<div class="container mt-5">
  <h1>Do you know the value of your product?</h1>
  <div class="mt-3">
    <button id="yesButton" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
    <button id="noButton" class="btn btn-secondary">No</button>
  </div>
  <div id="noPanel" class="mt-3 hidden">
    <div class="alert alert-info">Check the information</div>
  </div>
  <div id="yesPanel" class="mt-3 hidden">
    <button id="sellButton" class="btn btn-danger">I want to sell my product</button>
    <button id="keepButton" class="btn btn-success">I want to keep my product</button>
  </div>
  <div id="keepPanel" class="mt-3 hidden">
    <div class="alert alert-info">Choices 1 or 2 are best</div>
  </div>
  <div id="sellPanel" class="mt-3 hidden">
    <div class="alert alert-warning">Is your gain more than £3000?</div>
    <button id="gainYesButton" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
    <button id="gainNoButton" class="btn btn-secondary">No</button>
  </div>
  <div id="gainNoPanel" class="mt-3 hidden">
    <div class="alert alert-info">Option 3 is best</div>
  </div>
  <div id="gainYesPanel" class="mt-3 hidden">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">This means you'll pay CGT. Do you still want to sell?</div>
    <button id="cgtYesButton" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
    <button id="cgtNoButton" class="btn btn-secondary">No</button>
  </div>
  <div id="cgtNoPanel" class="mt-3 hidden">
    <div class="alert alert-info">Choices 1 or 2 are best</div>
  </div>
  <div id="cgtYesPanel" class="mt-3 hidden">
    <div class="alert alert-info">Choice 3 is best</div>
  </div>
</div>




The simplest would be: change a dataset value on BODY, and then use CSS to style the desired components, parts, panels. [data-mode=sell] #SOME_ID { } and in JS elBody.dataset.mode = "sell". Also instead of creating multiple handlers, target a data attribute as well and apply its value on click.

Please add the HTML that is needed to run this code. You can actually insert a runnable snippet in your question. Note that optimising code is not really the stuff that Stack Overflow deals with, so make sure to highlight the problem you have with this code. If there is no problem, it is off-topic here.

This kind of code suggests a poor articulation between HTML/CSS, and their ability to be programmed in JS. Without showing the whole thing, no valid refactoring can be proposed to you here.

Hello riospereira, You can add to the elements the class addHidden or removeHidden, and use getElementsByClassName( “xx” ), which returns an array, to which you can traverse and apply the necessary changes.

your buttons work in pairs... are they radio buttons? what is the CSS of hidden class ? +  How is the HTML hierarchy between your 8 Panels ?

@trincot HTML added

Are you using Bulma  as framework ?

You might find reading the site help section useful when it comes to asking a good question. To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a minimal reproducible example. Here's a question checklist you might find useful...

@MisterJojo I've now made my example work you can 'Run code snippet' to view it and no I'm not using Bulma or any other framework

As the setting of the visibility of panels concerns exactly the panels that follow below the panel that has the clicked button, and there is exactly one of those panels that should be visible, whose id can be derived from the id of the clicked button, you can generalise that process without much hard-coded id references.
You could attach only one click handler -- on the container element -- derive which is the panel that has the clicked button, and then iterate the remaining panels to set their visibility accordingly:


const container = document.querySelector("div.container");
const panels = [...container.children];

container.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target.tagName !== "BUTTON") return;
    const choice = document.getElementById(e.target.id.replace("Button", "Panel"));
    for (const panel of panels.slice(panels.indexOf(e.target.parentNode) + 1)) {
        panel.classList.toggle("hidden", panel !== choice);
    }
});
.hidden { display: none }
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container mt-5">
  <h1>Do you know the value of your product?</h1>
  <div class="mt-3">
    <button id="yesButton" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
    <button id="noButton" class="btn btn-secondary">No</button>
  </div>
  <div id="noPanel" class="mt-3 hidden">
    <div class="alert alert-info">Check the information</div>
  </div>
  <div id="yesPanel" class="mt-3 hidden">
    <button id="sellButton" class="btn btn-danger">I want to sell my product</button>
    <button id="keepButton" class="btn btn-success">I want to keep my product</button>
  </div>
  <div id="keepPanel" class="mt-3 hidden">
    <div class="alert alert-info">Choices 1 or 2 are best</div>
  </div>
  <div id="sellPanel" class="mt-3 hidden">
    <div class="alert alert-warning">Is your gain more than £3000?</div>
    <button id="gainYesButton" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
    <button id="gainNoButton" class="btn btn-secondary">No</button>
  </div>
  <div id="gainNoPanel" class="mt-3 hidden">
    <div class="alert alert-info">Option 3 is best</div>
  </div>
  <div id="gainYesPanel" class="mt-3 hidden">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">This means you'll pay CGT. Do you still want to sell?</div>
    <button id="cgtYesButton" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
    <button id="cgtNoButton" class="btn btn-secondary">No</button>
  </div>
  <div id="cgtNoPanel" class="mt-3 hidden">
    <div class="alert alert-info">Choices 1 or 2 are best</div>
  </div>
  <div id="cgtYesPanel" class="mt-3 hidden">
    <div class="alert alert-info">Choice 3 is best</div>
  </div>
</div>




Thank you @trincot this is exactly what I was looking for, what a nice, simple and clean solution, love it! This will help me a lot moving forwards in improving my JS skills, really appreciate your time, thanks again B]

Please delegate from the nearest static container. You can replace Button by Panel -


const panelHierarchy = [
    { prefix: 'yes', toggles: ['no', 'keep', 'sell', 'gainNo', 'gainYes', 'cgtNo', 'cgtYes'] },
    { prefix: 'no', toggles: ['yes', 'keep', 'sell', 'gainNo', 'gainYes', 'cgtNo', 'cgtYes'] },
    { prefix: 'keep', toggles: ['sell', 'gainNo', 'gainYes', 'cgtNo', 'cgtYes'] },
    { prefix: 'sell', toggles: ['keep', 'gainNo', 'gainYes', 'cgtNo', 'cgtYes'] },
    { prefix: 'gainNo', toggles: ['gainYes', 'cgtNo', 'cgtYes'] },
    { prefix: 'gainYes', toggles: ['gainNo', 'cgtNo', 'cgtYes'] },
    { prefix: 'cgtNo', toggles: ['cgtYes'] },
    { prefix: 'cgtYes', toggles: ['cgtNo'] }
];

const container = document.querySelector('.container');

container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const buttonId = e.target.id;
  if (!buttonId.endsWith('Button')) return;

  const clickedPrefix = buttonId.replace('Button', ''); // get the panel ID from the button ID
  const panelToShow = `${clickedPrefix}Panel`;

  // Get the panels to hide
  const panelsToHide = panelHierarchy
    .find(({ prefix }) => prefix === clickedPrefix)
    .toggles.map(toggleItem => `${toggleItem}Panel`);

  // Hide the toggled panels
  panelsToHide.forEach(panel => {
    document.getElementById(panel).classList.add('hidden');
  });

  // Show the clicked panel
  document.getElementById(panelToShow).classList.remove('hidden');
});
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.panel {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container mt-5">
  <h1>Do you know the value of your product?</h1>
  <div class="mt-3">
    <button id="yesButton" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
    <button id="noButton" class="btn btn-secondary">No</button>
  </div>
  <div id="noPanel" class="mt-3 hidden">
    <div class="alert alert-info">Check the information</div>
  </div>
  <div id="yesPanel" class="mt-3 hidden">
    <button id="sellButton" class="btn btn-danger">I want to sell my product</button>
    <button id="keepButton" class="btn btn-success">I want to keep my product</button>
  </div>
  <div id="keepPanel" class="mt-3 hidden">
    <div class="alert alert-info">Choices 1 or 2 are best</div>
  </div>
  <div id="sellPanel" class="mt-3 hidden">
    <div class="alert alert-warning">Is your gain more than £3000?</div>
    <button id="gainYesButton" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
    <button id="gainNoButton" class="btn btn-secondary">No</button>
  </div>
  <div id="gainNoPanel" class="mt-3 hidden">
    <div class="alert alert-info">Option 3 is best</div>
  </div>
  <div id="gainYesPanel" class="mt-3 hidden">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">This means you'll pay CGT. Do you still want to sell?</div>
    <button id="cgtYesButton" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
    <button id="cgtNoButton" class="btn btn-secondary">No</button>
  </div>
  <div id="cgtNoPanel" class="mt-3 hidden">
    <div class="alert alert-info">Choices 1 or 2 are best</div>
  </div>
  <div id="cgtYesPanel" class="mt-3 hidden">
    <div class="alert alert-info">Choice 3 is best</div>
  </div>
</div>




panels are hierarchical : Yes_No > Keep_Sell > gain  > cgt -> the 2 first panels impact all panels(8), the 2 last only 2.
